# How to pass parameters from fastColoredTextBox to webBrowser1 in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to pass parameters from fastColoredTextBox to webBrowser1 in Visual studio?

```html
webBrowser1.DocumentText = fastColoredTextBox1.Text;
```

- does not work...
  In richTextBox^

```html
private void richTextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = richTextBox1.Text:
        }
```

How to do it by analogy?
That is, I want the result to be immediately visible when writing HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Анатолий Бузов.

For updating the content of webBrowser1 to the text of fastColoredTextBox1, you can try the following code.

The complete code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Binding binding1 = new Binding("Text", webBrowser1, "DocumentText", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            fastColoredTextBox1.DataBindings.Add(binding1);

            webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            webBrowser1.Width = 400;
            Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
        }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
            webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
            webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new MyScriptObject(this);
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = fastColoredTextBox1.Text;
            webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fastColoredTextBox1.Language = FastColoredTextBoxNS.Language.HTML;
        }
        private void cToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fastColoredTextBox1.Language = FastColoredTextBoxNS.Language.CSharp;
        }
    }
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyScriptObject
    {
        private Form1 _form;
        public MyScriptObject(Form1 form)
        {
            _form = form;
        }
        public void Test(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
        }
    }
}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Hi, @ Анатолий Бузов.
Glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.